# iframe src via hash value

Tags: jquery, iframe

This works normally

```
<iframe class="iframe169" id="play323" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PTWx4FpIdys?rel=0"></iframe>
```

Why this doesn't work

```
<iframe class="iframe169" id="play323" src=""></iframe>
```

js

```
$(window).load(function() {
location.hash = "PTWx4FpIdys";
var a = location.hash;
var b = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + a + "?rel=0";
$('#play323').attr("src", b);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(document).ready()` as opposed to `$(window).load()`

Although this is an entirely separate issue from the question you've asked, the reason that it doesn't work properly is that you're assigning the video id to `location.hash` which prepends a `#` in front of the variable. SO the string that you actually get back is:

```
//www.youtube.com/embed/#PTWx4FpIdys
```

If you want to resolve this, then you need to remove the `#` from the string:

```
location.hash = "PTWx4FpIdys";
var a = location.hash.replace('#', '');
var b = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + a;
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8YB8/)